# Compose string query in postgresql function with NULL argument

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql function with this signature:

```
ver_hijos(
    IN cod character varying,
    IN idpadre integer,
    IN idhijo integer)
```

Into the body of the function I have the next:

```
     FOR var_r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || 
    ...........
    ' FROM '||....
     ' WHERE '||....
     ' AND 
        CASE WHEN ' || idpadre || ' IS NULL 
        THEN '||tabla_relacion||'.id_padre IS NULL 
        ELSE '||tabla_relacion||'.id_padre = '||idpadre||'
        END
        AND '||tabla_relacion||'.id_hijo = '||tabla_conceptos||'.id'
```

Function works fine when `idpadre` is not null, but if not, the  query string concatenate with a null string and it is invalidate, getting the next error:

```
ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function ver_hijos(character varying,integer,integer) line 10 at FOR over EXECUTE statement

********** Error **********

ERROR: query string argument of EXECUTE is null
SQL state: 22004
Context: PL/pgSQL function ver_hijos(character varying,integer,integer) line 10 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
```

¿How can I build the function properly for accept NULL values and don't damage the string?

Edit:

If I use format() for build the query:

```
     FOR var_r IN EXECUTE format('SELECT ' || 
            ...........
            ' FROM '||....
             ' WHERE '||....
             ' AND 
                CASE WHEN ' || idpadre || ' IS NULL 
                THEN '||tabla_relacion||'.id_padre IS NULL 
                ELSE '||tabla_relacion||'.id_padre = '||idpadre||'
                END
                AND '||tabla_relacion||'.id_hijo = |tabla_conceptos||'.id'
                ,idpadre,idpadre)
```

and I use null argument `idpadre=null` I get this error:

```
ERROR:  null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function ver_hijos(character varying,integer,integer) line 10 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier
SQL state: 22004
Context: PL/pgSQL function ver_hijos(character varying,integer,integer) line 10 at FOR over EXECUTE statement
```

It's my workaround for resolve it:

```
DECLARE
........
str_null_case character varying;
........
BEGIN
........
IF idpadre IS NULL THEN
    str_null_case := tabla_relacion||'.id_padre IS NULL';
ELSE
    str_null_case := tabla_relacion||'.id_padre = '||idpadre;
END IF;
........
BODY
.......
' WHERE '||tabla_conceptos||'.id ='|| idhijo ||
 ' AND '||str_null_case||    
 ' AND '||tabla_relacion||'.id_hijo = '||tabla_conceptos||'.id' 
.......
```

Comment: The `||` operator will yield `NULL` if any of the expressions is null. So most probably you are passing `null` in one of the parameters. To generate dynamic SQL `format()` is a **much** better choice in Postgres than concatenating with `||`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have edit the question, because if I use format() I have another error

Comment: Of course you get an error if that is null. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Definitively I can t manage a null value into a string :-(.  I would like to manage a null argument into the function. I was thinking a workaround like assign a negative value (because i'll never had it out of the function) to null value and then build the string with this condition, but I was wondering if there are best way to do it

Comment: But your parameter is not a "value", it's an identifier. You can't have a "null" identifier - which column would you test for `is null` if none is supplied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it like this:

```
EXECUTE '... CASE WHEN ' || (idpadre IS NULL) || ' THEN ...';
```

For the `ELSE` branch, you can use `coalesce(idpadre, '')`.

But it would be *much* better to write the whole thing as

```
EXECUTE format('... WHERE %I.id_padre IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $1',
               tabla_relacion)
USING idpadre;
```

This is simpler and avoids the danger of SQL injection.

Comment: This resolves perfectly the first part of the string, but not the second one: "ELSE '||tabla_relacion||'.id_padre = '||idpadre||'". Finally, after a few hours trying to advance in this way, I have resolved it using a previous string: str_null_case. I have edited the main because if someone consider it useful, but I'm not happy with my "solution" :-(

Comment: I improved the answer.